# Internet Explorer 11 missing compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

In Internet Explorer 11 How to check compatibility view of IE9 and IE10 which defaultly find something and I couldn't change myself from ie11 to ie9 or ie10.

I googled and not found anything as useful.Below is one of them but using ie10 I can get all lower version compatible view but that is not possible using ie11.

```
To change your Compatibility View settings
Open Internet Explorer for the desktop, click Tools, and then click Compatibility View settings.
In the Compatibility View Settings box, add the problematic website URL, and then click Add.
Compatibility View is turned on for this single website, for this specific computer.
Decide if you want your intranet sites displayed using Compatibility View, decide whether to use Microsoft compatibility lists, and then click Close.
```

Comment: should be on super user.

Comment: Sorry what you mean by "Should be super user"

Comment: I mean superuser.com our sister site.

Comment: why should this be on superuser?

Comment: are you saying you can't see the compat icon in the omnibar? have you tried f12?

Comment: yes icon not available in ie11 as it is in ie10

Comment: @albert the question is unclear as to whether this a programming question or a user question. Since not programming is mentioned I think this defaults to superuser.com

Comment: @PreetSangha i do not know any users that are aware of compatibility modes, so to me it does not default to superuser.com. it is all relative, was just curious as to your reasoning behind which to use. thanks.

Comment: again....have you tried hitting f12?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press F12 to open IE11's developer tools, then go to the bottom option in the left hand side bar (Emulation). There you can select the Document mode you wish, each representing a different IE version.